# Don't indent in p tag when there is a img tag in it

Tags: css, text-indent

Here is my html architecture:(I can not change the architecture because it is generated by Markdown.

```
<p><img src="foo.png" /></p>
```

I have set text-indent in my css file:

```
p {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

Problem is when my image is very large, some part of my image may be in the outside of my container.
I hava set `max-width: 100%` for img tag.

[image]

You can see that a little part of the arrow is in the outside of the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just offset the indentation on the image by doing something like:

```
p > img {
    margin-left:-2em;
}
```

Does that solve your issue or is there something I'm missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/YvMCV/

Answer (score 0):

When you set img width to 100%, it does just that, regardless of `text-indent` or `padding`.  The amount that the image has overflown is `2em`, the width of your `text-indent`.  You could use % instead of em to set `text-indent` and have your img width be what's left over...

```
p {
    text-indent: 1%;
}

p img {
    width: 99%;
}
```

OR, do as the other answer mentions and set img to `margin-left: -2em;`.